# merge arrays where some value of parent arrays is not equals

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I array of arrays, what look something like that:

```
$messages = array (
  0 => 
     array(
     'keyT' => 'id.key'
     'mess' => array(
         array(1,0)
     )
...
)
```

I want to merge `mess` preperties of arrays where `'keyT'` is not equals.
I run trought the arrays:

```
foreach ($messages as $k => $current) {
    foreach ($messages as $ke => $all) {
      if ($current['keyT'] == $all['keyT']) {
          array_merge( ... )
      }
    }
}
```

But this not deve me any results. Maybe somebody can help me. Thanks!

Comment: You wrote "I want to merge mess preperties of arrays where 'keyT' is not equals" but in your code I see that you try to merge if keyT is equal. Is it a typo in problem description ?

Comment: @JakubFilipczyk, yes my mistake where they equal sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$messages = array(
    0 =>
    array(
        'keyT' => 'A',
        'mess' => array(
            array(1, 0)
        )
    ),
    1 =>
    array(
        'keyT' => 'A',
        'mess' => array(
            array(1, 2)
        )
    ),
    2 =>
    array(
        'keyT' => 'B',
        'mess' => array(
            array(3, 4)
        )
    )
);

$result = array();
foreach ($messages as $msg) {
    $key = $msg['keyT'];
    if (!isset($result[$key])) {
        $result[$key] = array();
    }
    $result[$key] = array_merge($result[$key], $msg['mess']);
}

print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                )

        )

    [B] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => 4
                )

        )

)
```